# Incorrect syntax near 'minute' when passing expression to stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I have the following code:

```
insert into @Precalculo (descripcion, Valor) 
  exec dbo.GetRankingTotalizador 
    @Fecha, 
    DateAdd(minute, (-1), DateAdd(day, 1, @Fecha)), 
    @cadenas, 
    @familias

insert into PrecalculoComparativaSemanal 
  select @Fecha, @cadenas, @familias, [1], [2], [3], [4] FROM
  (select Descripcion, Valor from @Precalculo) p 
  PIVOT (min(Valor) FOR Valor in ([1], [2], [3], [4])) as pvt
```

It gives me an error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1
>   Incorrect syntax near 'minute'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For one, you can't use an expression as an argument to a stored procedure. Try:

```
DECLARE @d DATETIME;
SET @d =  DateAdd(minute, (-1), DateAdd(day, 1, @Fecha));

insert into @Precalculo (descripcion, Valor) 
  exec dbo.GetRankingTotalizador @Fecha, @d, @cadenas, @familias;
```

Next, depending on your version of SQL Server, @table variables haven't always been a valid target for `INSERT/EXEC`. I forget when this was made valid, but you may need to use a #temp table instead.

Finally, I strongly recommend:

```
insert into PrecalculoComparativaSemanal (missing, column, list)
```